# visual basic write to text file

Tags: visual-studio

I have a question about using **StreamWriter** in visual basic 2008
, Below is code for database filtering using visual basic 2008

```
  On Error Resume Next

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ''  Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"
        For i As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
                If Table1DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtsearch.Text Then
                    ''if item found then we play sound ok
                    My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
                    My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
                    temp = 1

                    ''write the user name that logged in
                    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
                    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\haydeer\Desktop\test.txt", True)
                    file.WriteLine(txtsearch.Text)
                    file.Close()
                    txtsearch.Text = ""

                End If
            Next
        Next
        '' trytime += 1 'Increment if not found
        If temp = 0 And trytime <= 2 Then 'Check if not found 3 times (or more)

            ''if item not found then we play sound err
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\computer_access.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
            Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.MydbDataSet.Table1)
            Me.Table1DataGridView.Refresh()
            trytime += 1 'Increment if not found
            txtsearch.Text = ""

        ElseIf temp = 0 And trytime >= 3 Then
            '' Alarm Gose on
            MsgBox("three time")

        End If
    End If
```

my problem is when the user is logged-in it will write the date of login for that user, iam successful store the user , but i want to store the date too for example (00:00:00 AM)? any idea ?

Comment: Why the vb6 tag, if you are using vb.net?

Comment: i didnt know it was tagged ;)

Answer (score 0):

To turn the current time on the machine to a string:

`My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToLongTimeString` (1:23:45 AM)

`My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToShortTimeString` (1:23 AM)

`My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToLongDateString` (Saturday, January 1, 2000)

`My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToShortDateString` (1/1/2000)

`My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToString` (1/1/2000 1:23:45 AM) ***I suggest this one***

-Mg